# Sort a jQuery datatable by UK date and ignore empty cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, date, datatables

How can I make the empty cell stick to the bottom when sorting date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format? My problem is in here (sort the age column) : http://jsfiddle.net/dup75/11/

```
$('#hr_curriculum_interns').dataTable( {
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sType": "date-uk" },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]
});
```

the famous code in here is seen on http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4025/sorting-to-ignore-empty-cells which code is :

```
    $.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['mystring-asc'] = function(x,y) {
    var retVal;
    x = x.replace('&nbsp;', '');
    y = y.replace('&nbsp;', '');

    if (x == y) retVal = 0;
    else if (x.substr(0,1) == "{" && y.substr(0,1) == "{") {
        if (x > y) retVal=  1;
        else retVal =  -1;
    }
    else if (x.substr(0,1) == "{") retVal =  1;
    else if (y.substr(0,1) == "{") retVal =  -1;

    else if (x > y) retVal=  1;
    else return -1;

    return retVal;
}
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['mystring-desc'] = function(y,x) {
    var retVal;
    x = x.replace('&nbsp;', '');
    y = y.replace('&nbsp;', '');

    if (x == y) retVal= 0;
    else if (x.substr(0,1) == "{" && y.substr(0,1) == "{") {
        if (x > y) retVal=  -1;
        else retVal =  1;
    }  
    else if (x.substr(0,1) == "{") retVal =  -1;
    else if (y.substr(0,1) == "{") retVal =  1;

    else if (x > y) retVal =  1;
    else return -1;

    return retVal;
 }
```

but it doesnt fixed my problem in sorting my column "age" in dd/mm/yyy format.
it just making my column in an integer format, which should not be because its in a date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [**updated fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dup75/17/) or StackSnippet below. Basically you need to implement a custom sorting function. Here is the code of that sorting function along with explanation:

```js
// add a set of custom sorting functions
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "customdatesort-pre": function(a) {
    // returns the "weight" of a cell value
    var r, x;
    if (a === null || a === "") {
      // for empty cells: weight is a "special" value which needs special handling
      r = false;
    } else {
      // otherwise: weight is the "time value" of the date
      x = a.split("/");
      r = +new Date(+x[2], +x[1] - 1, +x[0]);
    }
    console.log("[PRECALC] " + a + " becomes " + r);
    return r;
  },
  "customdatesort-asc": function(a, b) {
    // return values are explained in Array.prototype.sort documentation
    if (a === false && b === false) {
      // if both are empty cells then order does not matter
      return 0;
    } else if (a === false) {
      // if a is an empty cell then consider a greater than b
      return 1;
    } else if (b === false) {
      // if b is an empty cell then consider a less than b
      return -1;
    } else {
      // common sense
      return a - b;
    }
  },
  "customdatesort-desc": function(a, b) {
    if (a === false && b === false) {
      return 0;
    } else if (a === false) {
      return 1;
    } else if (b === false) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return b - a;
    }
  }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hr_curriculum_interns').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [{
        "sType": "customdatesort"
      },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">


<div class="container">
  <table id="hr_curriculum_interns" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>-</th>
        <th>-</th>
        <th>-</th>
        <th>-</th>
        <th>-</th>
        <th>-</th>
        <th>-</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>31/12/2015</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>31/12/2014</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14/11/2014</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>31/12/2013</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
        <td>Athos</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thank you @salman.. but how can i make it work using a classname to target the header i want to sort to? thanks ^_^

Comment: You read the manual! It seems datatables changed a lot of things recently so I am not sure.

Comment: he-he-he. thanks for scolding me, i got it working now, thanks Godbless :DDD http://jsfiddle.net/xawixawxaw/dup75/19/

Comment: hi @salman can you explain what's the meaning of the "+" in the `r = +new Date(+x[2], +x[1] - 1, +x[0]);` thanks for the help!

Comment: `+` converts the expression into a number e.g. if `x[2]` is the string `"2014"` then `+x[2]` returns the _number_ `2014` (you can use `parseInt` instead).

Comment: Likewise `+new Date(...)` converts the Date object to a number, which would be the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 (you can use `new Date(...).getTime()`).

Comment: Hi, I have implemented your code as it is. But the problem is, I'm getting only the empty value inside the "customdatesort-pre" 'a' parameter value but not the field with values in it. I think , I am getting the result. I don't know what to do with this now. Kindly help me.